# How to use multiple functions at once?

Tags: python, function, global

```
def add_course(gc, course):
    global gpacalc
    global creditcalc
    gpacalc = gpacalc + (gc * course)
    creditcalc = (course + creditcalc)
def gpa():
    return (gpacalc/creditcalc)
def credit_total():
    return(creditcalc)
```

I am trying to write a  file named gpa.py that computes a cumulative GPA using three functions: add_course adds a new course to the running total, and gpa and credit_total gets your cumulative GPA and credit count, respectively. I am attempting to use two global variables to keep track of GPA and credits (both initially 0).

-Invoking gpa.add_course(3.7, 3) should add a 3-credit course with GPA 3.7 to the running GPA and credit count total.
-Invoking gpa.gpa() should retrieve your current total GPA.
-Invoking gpa.credit_total() should retrieve your current total credits earned.
-Invoking gpa.add_course with only one argument (e.g., gpa.add_course(3.7)) should add a 3-credit course.

What am I doing wrong within my code? I am trying to have both the functions nor the file itself containing any print or asking for any input.

Comment: I wasn't aware you could use globals like that. I suggest you don't. :-)

Comment: How will this code be used? Will these functions be imported by another program? Will the gpa.py script be called on its own? How do the functions get their input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are throwing a number of things into your code that don't behave the way you expect, because Python is interpreting things differently than you expect. I recommend stepping back and going through a Python tutorial such as learnpython.org, it'll save you a huge amount of time and hassle.

Given the approach you are taking, here is a version that works, with some comments on what I changed.

```
gpacalc = 0
creditcalc = 0

# If you want the course argument to be optional, 
# you need to provide a default value for it.
def add_course(gc, course = 3):
    global gpacalc
    global creditcalc
    # += is the concise way to increment a value:
    gpacalc += gc * course
    creditcalc += course

def gpa():
    # No need to use parenthesis for this return value 
    # unless you intend the result to be in tuple form.
    return gpacalc/creditcalc

def credit_total():
    # Same here, no need for parenthesis.
    return creditcalc


add_course(3.7, 3)
print(gpa())            # 3.7000000000000006
print(credit_total())   # 3
add_course(3.7)         
print(credit_total())   # 6
```